# Array of strings to array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string, 2d

I have an array of strings in PHP like this:

```
people = array("John","Kim");
```

I want to convert each of those strings into arrays themselves.  Basically, I now want a 2-dimensional array like

```
people(John[],Kim[]);
```

I've been struggling with the implementation and am not sure how to do it.

Comment: So you want `array('John' => array(), 'Kim' => array())`?

Comment: what do you want those arrays to contain - the letters of the name, like ['j','o','h',n']?

Comment: So I'm eventually going to have a 4-dimensional array.  people[names[purchases[number of that purchase]]]], like people[John[couch[2]]]].  I'm basically implementing a tree using arrays.

Comment: adding time and space?
(4-dimensional is a misnomer - you have 2 dimension  over, and down - height, and width.   Some complex DBs add a 3rd dimension, time)

Comment: And even so, people[John[couch[2]]]] is not the best design, try something more meaningful using keys:  {john:{purchase="chair",price="100",qty="2"},stephanie:{...} }, OR BETTER YET, use some people, and purchase objects instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$people = array_fill_keys(array("John","Kim"), array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you should be using a combination of keys or values if you want to do this with multi dimensional arrays (which I'm not sure is the best way, but can't say w/o further context).

```
$people = array(
   "john" => array()
   );
```

Then when you want to add products, just go like:

```
$people["john"]["couch"] = 3; // bought 3 times.
$people["john"][$item] = 0; // if you don't know the count yet for whatever reason.  You can always chagne it later the same way.
```

Now:

```
 foreach( $people as $person => $purchases ){
    echo UCFirst( $person );
    if( ! empty( $purchases ) ){
       echo ' has bought:<br />';
       foreach( $purchases as $item => $qty ){
          echo $item.' ('.$qty.')<br />';
       }
    }
 }
```

I would recommend always making your keys either uppercase or lowercase if you are going to use named.  Your call though.

If you give us more code / context, there may be much better ways to do this stuff.

Comment: I basically have a list of people, and each item they have purchased, and how many of those items they have purchased.  I'm outputting that information in csv to use with highcharts.js.  A tree made the most sense in my head, but please let me know if there's a better way.